# Update existing rows with values of new row if given field is identical

Tags: mysql, sql-update, sql-insert

My MySQL knowledge is a bit shaky. I have a table with (among others) the following columns/values:

```
ID | importID | distID | email     | street       | city
-----------------------------------------------------------
25 | 5        | 2      | abc@d.com | Main Road    | London
-----------------------------------------------------------
26 | 5        | 2      | mno@e.com | Oak Alley    | York
-----------------------------------------------------------
27 | 5        | 2      | pqr@s.com | Tar Pits     | London
-----------------------------------------------------------
28 | 5        | 2      | xyz@a.com | Fleet Street | London
-----------------------------------------------------------
...
-----------------------------------------------------------
99 | -1       | 2      | abc@d.com | New Street   | Exeter
```

I do some checks when new rows are inserted: validate email addresses, find doublets with different dist(ributor)ID etc.

One of the tasks is "update existing rows with data of the freshly imported row when column "email" is identical" (yes, there can be multiple rows with identical email addresses).

At the time this task is performed, the importID of the currently inserted rows is always -1. I tried aliasing with all kinds of variations of

```
UPDATE table orig table dup
SET orig.street = dup.street, orig.city = dup.city
WHERE orig.email = dup.email
```

or joining with numerous variations of

```
UPDATE table orig
JOIN 
  (SELECT email FROM table
  WHERE importID != -1) dup
ON orig.email = dup.email
SET orig.street = dup.street, orig.city = dup.city
```

What is my mistake?

Comment: I disagree with the approach.  You should avoid storing duplicate information like this, or, if you must, then use a timestamp to differentiate between current and old.

Comment: I understand what you mean. The point behind this approach is that I have one big table containing all data. Records can come from different imports, belong to different distributors and many more. I could differentiate between existing and new rows using the importID - but when the records are imported from a csv file, that import record is not created yet. That's why a new import gets a -1, which is changed to the correct import ID later. I could change that, but it would mean quite an amount of work and time - which I do not have at the moment ... :(

Comment: Add sample table data to your question if you can.

Comment: Added sample data and changed field names that should be updated, since it is much more likely that addresses change rather than names ;)

Comment: So what exactly is your question? Update all records having import id <> -1 with records having import id = -1?

Comment: Thank you everybody, and sorry you had to wait for so long.

After some thought I decided to follow Rick James, and I changed my approach (which took me a while).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't do it that way.

Store the duplicate email information in a separate table.  That table is to contain records that are awaiting analysis and confirmation; do not try to include them in the main table.

This extra table can have multiple rows with the same email, but the main table must not.

The person processing the pending changes would use a `SELECT` into both tables (either two Selects or a Union), make a decision, and poke a button.  One button would say to toss the new info; one would say to replace; etc.

And, as Tim suggests, have a `TIMESTAMP` in each table.  This will assist the user in making changes, especially if there are multiple pending changes.

Answer (score 0):

Given that it would be better to change the approach, you could code your requirement as follow:

```
UPDATE mytab INNER JOIN mytab AS newrec ON mytab.email=newrec.email AND newrec.importID=-1
   SET mytab.street=newrec.street, mytab.city=newrec.city;
```

**Example**

Before

```
ID  importID distID email       street       city
25  5        2      abc@d.com   Main Road    London
26  5        2      mno@e.com   Oak Alley    York
27  5        2      pqr@s.com   Tar Pits     London
28  5        2      xyz@a.com   Fleet Street London
99  -1       2      abc@d.com   New Street   Exeter
100 -1       2      pqr@s.com   foo          bar
```

After

```
ID  importID distID email       street       city
25  5        2      abc@d.com   New Street   Exeter
26  5        2      mno@e.com   Oak Alley    York
27  5        2      pqr@s.com   foo          bar
28  5        2      xyz@a.com   Fleet Street London
99  -1       2      abc@d.com   New Street   Exeter
100 -1       2      pqr@s.com   foo          bar
```